# Buttons in PyQT are all being assigned the same function

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt6

I am currently making an application in python with pyqt6 that has a toolbar. The tools will definitely change over time and I want it to extendable by users in the future, so I have a yaml file that describes the tools. It is formatted as shown below.

```yaml
add_layer:
    desc: "Add a layer above current selected layer" 
    iconPath: ".\icons\plus-circle.svg" 
    func: "addLayer"
del_layer: 
    desc: "Delete curret layer" 
    iconPath: ".\icons\minus-circle.svg" 
    func: "placeholderFunction"
```

The code for making the toolbar and buttons is shown below. self.model is a class that contains most of the actual data and functions. addLayer and placeholderFunctions are methods of the model class.

```py
def createToolBar(self, location, *args):
    self.toolBar = QToolBar(*args)
    self.addToolBar(location, self.toolBar)

    buttons = self.createButtonsFromYAML(".\\icons\\icons.yaml")

    for button in buttons:
        self.toolBar.addAction(button)

def createButtonsFromYAML(self, path: str): 
    buttons = [] 
    with open(path, "r") as stream: 
        try: 
            buttonDef = yaml.safe_load(stream) 
        except yaml.YAMLError as exc: 
            print(exc)    

        for button, props in buttonDef.items():
            action = QAction(
                QIcon(props["iconPath"]),
                button,
                self
            )
            func = getattr(Model, props["func"])
            action.triggered.connect(lambda _: func(self.model))
            action.setStatusTip(props["desc"])
            if "shortcut" in props:
                action.setShortcut(props["shortcut"])

            buttons.append(action)

    return buttons
```

The problem that I am facing is that both buttons trigger the bottom trigger the bottom most function described in the yaml.

The icons are correct, and I have verified that `props["func"]` returns the correct value, and that the QAction objects being assigned in the top function are correct (at least they have the same memory addresses). If I change the order of `add_layer` and `del_layer`, both buttons will call `add_layer`.

Any help is appreciated with this, thank you.

The full codebase can be found here, https://github.com/Luke5273/Cryptamap